# How achieve Bold-Italic style ins vscode theme json file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Recently, I was editing a VS Code theme `.json` file.
I wanted to achieve ***Bold-Italic*** style for my theme, but I am confused in this part:

```
   {
      "name": "Keywords",
      "scope": "keyword",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#8A31B9",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      }
    },
```

in `"fontStyle": "bold"` it will either take `"bold"` or `"italic"`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add italic and bold in the same line.

```
 {
      "name": "Keywords",
      "scope": "keyword",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#8A31B9",
        "fontStyle": "bold italic"
      }
    },
```

Comment: thank you, this worked for me, actually initially it showed error when I tried to put 2 together.

Comment: No problem at all!